# Getting Mail Twice

Tags: javascript, php, email

I have created a mail [thanks to the support of this community]. I am fetching and sending info from a contact form that have drop down lists and everything looks fine but the problem is that I am getting the same mail twice and I have no idea what is wrong in it. I don't have much PHP or JavaScript skills.

Below is the Contact form -

```html
<div class="contact-form">
<h2>Contact Us</h2>              
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 function verify() {
  if(document.getElementById("name").value=="" || document.getElementById("email").value=="") {
   alert("Please enter a name and an email.");
  } else {
   alert("Looks good, sending email");
   //document.getElementById('ContactForm').submit();
   var name=$('#name').val();
   var email=$('#email').val();
   var message=$('#message').val();
   var phone=$('#phone').val();
   var law=$('#law').val();
   var fine=$('#fine').val();
   var  formData = "name="+name+"&message="+message+"&phone="+phone+"&law="+law+"&fine="+fine+"&email="+email;
   $.ajax({
    url : "mail.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
     //data - response from server
     alert(data);
    },
   });
  }
 }
</script>
    
                        
<form action="mail.php" method="post" id="ContactForm">
  
<p>Your Name: * <br>
 <input type="text" class="form-bt" value="" size="40" name="name" id="name" required>
</p>
  
<p>Phone: *<br>
 <input type="number" class="form-bt" value="" size="40" name="phone" id="phone" required>
</p>
  
<p>Email: *<br>
 <input type="email" class="form-bt" value="" size="40" name="email" id="email" required>
</p>
  
<p>Are of Law * <br>
 <select name="law" class="form-bt" id="law">
  <option value="Business & Commercial" selected>Business & Commercial</option>
  <option value="Landlord & Tenant">Landlord & Tenant</option>
  <option value="Litigation & Disputes">Litigation & Disputes</option>
  <option value="Employment Law">Employment Law</option>
   <option value="Wills & Probate">Wills & Probate</option>
  <option value="Others">Others</option>
 </select>
</p>
  
<p>Enquiry Details: *<br>
 <textarea cols="40" rows="10" class="form-bt" name="message" id="message" required></textarea>
</p>
  
<p>How Did You Find Us? * <br>
 <select name="fine" class="form-bt" id="fine">
   <option value="I am a Previous or Existing Client" selected>I am a Previous or Existing Client</option>
   <option value="Online Search">Online Search</option>
   <option value="Advertisement">Advertisement</option>
   <option value="Word of Mouth">Word of Mouth</option>
    <option value="Law Society "Find a Solicitor"">Law Society "Find a Solicitor"</option>
   <option value="Bar Standards Board">Bar Standards Board</option>
   <option value="Other">Other</option>
 </select>
</p>
  
<p>Please Specify: <br>
 <input type="text" class="form-bt" value="" size="40" name="specify" id="specify">
</p>
  
<p>
 <input type="submit" id="send" onClick="verify()" value="Submit" class="btton">
</p>
</form>

</div><!-- Contact Form --> 

Now, i have created a mail.php files and have included the below codes - 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

Everything is fine. I am receiving the mail.

Note: I don't also want to redirect people to this URL - http://www.XXXX.net/law/ any idea how i can do that?

kind regards
deb

Comment: Try **onClick="verify(); return false;"**

Comment: Sending mail via AJAX call then there is no need to place `hearder()` calling.

Comment: Handle redirect into success of AJAX.

Comment: remove header code from there.that's it

Comment: @hherger hi where should i place the code? i am a noob in javascript

Comment: At the end of the form where the "submit" button is declared: _<input type="submit" id="send" onClick="verify()" value="Submit" class="btton">_

Answer (score 0):

You submit your form via the default submit button **and** do an request request again if validation passes via the onclick event.

The solution is simple:

Change in your form submit button `input type="submit"` to `input type="button"`

> Due the button type, only the onclick event will be excecuted, so verify() validates and send the mail if the validation passes.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX with redirection like:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "mail.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        //data - response from server
        //alert(data);

        window.location="http://www.XXXX.net/law/";
    },

});
```

Send mail functionality like:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$law = $_POST['law']; 
$fine = $_POST['fine']; 


$formcontent=" From: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone: $phone \n Are of Law: $law \n How Did You Find Us: $fine \n Enquiry Details: $message";
$recipient = "devtest@XXXX.org";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" ;
```

Comment: Solutions .. hi i have updated them but i am still reciving two mails 

and also i don't want the page to redirect to example.com/mail.php page any solutions?

Comment: Your _mail.php_ calling two times. **1**. Via AJAX **2**.Via form action